# How to configure personal info in package.json

Tags: github, npm, package.json, npm-scripts

I have a public GitHub [repository](https://github.com/mikehedman/planks) that contains information that is specific to my use in the project's package.json file.  Specifically, the deployment script has my deployment target hardcoded into it:

```json
"scripts": {
  "deploy": "NODE_ENV=production npm run build && surge -p public -d planks.mikehedman.com"
},
```

Instead, I would like to pull the `planks.mikehedman.com` part from somewhere else (ideally some place that would not be part of the version controlled repository).

Is there a best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a local environment variable that would be set to a default value if not present. For example :

```json
"scripts": {
    "deploy": "REMOTE=${REMOTE:=planks.public.com};NODE_ENV=production npm run build && surge -p public -d $REMOTE"
}
```

On your machine you would have :

```
export REMOTE=planks.mikehedman.com
```

That would be in your `.bashrc` or `/etc/environment`